# Pinterest button on page tab app in Facebook

Tags: facebook, pinterest

Can anyone answer this ?

Trying to get Pinterest button onto a facebook page tab app for an image to be pinned. With the documentation at pinterest, its based on an actual link in the code. Since I do not know the page tab url for the app, is there any other way round this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you know the page tab URL? Unless I'm missing something in the question, wouldn't it be something along the lines of...

https://www.facebook.com/cocacola/app_161193133389

...where "cocacola" is the page name and "161193133389" is the app ID?

And if THAT doesn't work for some reason, you could capture the URL with window.location.href, no?